# how to run multiple SQL statements in a clientdataset or fdquery?

Tags: delphi-xe7

I'm using the statement below:

```
procedure TdtmdlImportacao.DeleteParticipante;
begin
  fdqryDelete.Active := False;
  fdqryDelete.SQL.Clear;
  fdqryDelete.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM PARTICIPANTE');
  fdqryDelete.ExecSQL;
end;

procedure TdtmdlImportacao.DeleteProduto;
begin
  fdqryDelete.Active := False;
  fdqryDelete.SQL.Clear;
  fdqryDelete.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM PRODUTO');
  fdqryDelete.ExecSQL;
end;
```

I would like to make a delete all.

Comment: What database are you using? Whether this is possible or not depends in part on the DBMS.

Comment: I'm using firebird but I believe that I will need to postgres too.

Comment: Is there any deeper intention for using one query for all? Looking for a **golden ring** query? Do you know, you can execute a statement direct with `TFDConnection.ExecSQL`?

Comment: I'm not able to separate a statement from the other and run it all at once ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
begin
  fdqryDelete.Active := False;
  fdqryDelete.SQL.Clear;
  fdqryDelete.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM PARTICIPANTE;');
  fdqryDelete.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM PRODUTO;');
  fdqryDelete.ExecSQL;
end;
```

with ";" at the end of each row inside ' '?